# Computer slows when battery is low

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, performance

My Macbook Pro running Mountain Lion slows down dramatically when the battery is below 4-5%. All the applications running are very slow to respond, and several have the "Application not responding" message when I right-click on them in the dock. Now everything works fine when the battery is above 5%, so I'm wondering what goes on when the battery is low that causes the performance drag. Basically, I have two questions:

1. What is causing this lag (for the sake of curiosity)?
2. How can I fix it (for the sake of practicality)?

**System Info:**

- **Device:** Macbook Pro (Spring 2012) 13-Inch running Mountain Lion (10.8)
- **Memory:** 8GB
- **Processor:** 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7
- **Storage:** 500GB SSD Drive with more than half free

Comment: It sounds like CPU speed stepping to me.

Comment: has the provided answer solved your problem? Because I don't see any of the described settings in 10.8

Comment: @barbaz - It didn't really solve the problem, but it seems like there is no solution so I accepted it.

Comment: Same problem with MacBook Air 2013.

Comment: I'd really like to find a solution to this, it's annoying for me as I can't do any work with the last 10% of battery life, so it's effectively dead anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See if this link provides you with some useful knowledge. http://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-processor-speed-macbook-pro-43635.html

It's likely that the MBP is automatically scaling the processing power back to conserve battery power, but that isn't necessarily the only cause.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, the same thing happens on my MacBook Air (11 inch, 2014) when the battery gets around 5%, performance drops significantly, it does this because your battery level is so low, just plug it in a charger and it will start working normally again.
If this doesn't solve it, try resetting the SMC.

Comment: Soooo is there a command I can run or a kernel change I can make to prevent this??