# Can CPU Speed Stepping be prevented?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, battery, performance

A while ago, I asked a [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61293/computer-slows-when-battery-is-low) regarding the reason behind my computer slowing when it had ~5% battery or less. I was told that it was either CPU speed stepping or the Macbook Pro automatically scaling back the processing power to conserve battery power.

---

Building on that question, I'm wondering how I would prevent the computer from either undergoing CPU speed stepping or from scaling the processing power back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unlikely you will find a reliable and trivial tool for changing the processor's low level power management away from Apple's recommendations.

As a user, you are limited to the options available in the Energy Saver panel of System Preferences and [pmset](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html).

To stop the processor stepping up or down depending on power available, will require a custom kernel extension.

[OS X's power management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2075/_index.html) is handled by a layer called [IOKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html) within the kernel. Writing code within the IOKit is not trivial; mistakes can induce kernel panics and do serious harm to the system's stability.

As of 10.8.2, OS X considers 20% battery to be the first stage of a low battery warning.

If your battery is at 5%, it is likely your Mac will shortly be entering emergency sleep or hibernation mode in order to safeguard your data.

Comment: Surely somebody has written something like this... but I can't find anything on github :(  have you guys solved this?